# Input field regex pattern prevent last 3 characters from being: lowercase, uppercase, uppercase?

Tags: html, regex

Trying to stop a spam bot with html5 pattern.  Can regex be written to prevent the input field from ending in: lowercase, uppercase, uppercase?

Few of spam bot examples I'm trying to stop:

```
AprilWexKV
MayfielpHL
pinupkazinoNK
```

PS ended up need to rethink my regex pattern and this is what I ended up using to:

```
^.+([a-z]{3}|[A-Z]{3})$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? `.+[a-z][A-Z]{2}`

Or inverse logic: `^.+(?<![a-z][A-Z]{2})$` or `^.+([a-z]{3}|[A-Z]{3})$`

Comment: Input field is a lastname field so this should (work/match): SMITH, Smith, smith.  This should not work:  smiTH

Comment: I'm confused, this regex will match on smiTH but not on SMITH, Smith or smith as intended.

Comment: Sorry then I have it all wrong.  I want it to do the opposite.  Because if I put pattern=".+[a-z][A-Z]{2}" in my input form only the spam bot will be able to sign up.  Sorry I'm really new to regex.  I guess now I see that what I really need to do is make sure all 3 last characters MUST be either uppercase, or lowercase.  And it should not be a mix of upper and lower.  That would prevent the bot from filling the input, if the bot is manually filling it out but as @mplungjan has said bot probably isn't doing it manually

Comment: Ah ok well the inverse of that regex would be to use a lookbehind: `^.+(?<![a-z][A-Z]{2})$` or if lookbehind is not supported, you could hardcode the opposite logic `^.+([a-z]{3}|[A-Z]{3})$`.

Comment: By the way, enforcing a pattern with HTML5 will only work on browsers that support HTML5 inputs. If the browser doesn't understand the regex attribute, it'll just ignore it. It's definitely better to sanitize the inputs on the server side, like the other answer says.

Comment: Thanks very much, that does exactly want I needed. And yes definitely, I will have someone put it on the server side if this doesn't stop one annoying spam bot I have an issue with.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop a spambot on the client. They do not sit and type their fake userIDs
They have automated services that load your form, ignores all JavaScript and fills in the fields with whatever their scripts want.

You have to filter them on the server.

Comment: I understand that it's probably not filling it out manually on my site, I was hoping to confirm that by adding this pattern.  And I just realized I was looking at my pattern all wrong.  What my pattern needs to do is check that the last 3 characters MUST ONLY be ALL either uppercase, or lowercase.  And it should NOT be a mix of upper and lower to stop the bot.  I was trying to match what the bot is doing, instead I should be matching legitimate user inputs.